# Rearranging TR position using the TD ID (Work only in the first element)

Tags: javascript

I'm rearranging a table using only javascript, each TD has a ID that I compare with the rowIndex of the Table.

The problem is when I run the code, only the first Element work, you can see in the images below, what's happening ?

```
let trs =  document.querySelectorAll(".tr-row");
let tds = document.querySelectorAll(".td-descr");
let tbodyAtivo = document.querySelector("#tbody-ativo");

tds.forEach((td) =>{
    trs.forEach((tr) => {
              let trPai = td.closest("tr") //tr of each element   
              if (tr.rowIndex == td.id) //rowIndex
                tbodyAtivo.insertBefore(trPai,tbodyAtivo[tr.rowIndex]); //insert de new element

    })
})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why `tr.rowIndex == td.id` condition? In html, rowIndex is 12 but id is 4. Condition will fail

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How should the data look like? I think you want to do something that can be achieved with a single query.

Comment: @Sunil, the rowIndex order by 1 to all many trs I have right ? My expectation is move the tr to the Position of the index

Comment: @adelriosantiago I realy want to use the query, but the query returns a 20 coluns , and the result is a sum of 12 months and 4 quarters and total. In the query I need to use this 
(
classificacao IN ('630','567','2016','2017','5148','700','2.1.04.01','2.1.05.01','2.1.06.02','6145','2786','2261','6151','6125','2.2.01.06','854','882','966','980')
OR 
codigo IN ('630','567','2016','2017','5148','700','6145','2786','2261','6151','6125','854','882','966','980')
)

So I don't know exactly the position of the elements a only know after run, if mysql order by allowed pass a custom order maybe..

Comment: Get TD by its ID, then get the parent TR and move it. There's no need for loops. Note: I use to apply the ID to TR and I can move them easier.

Comment: I followed the recommendation of @adelriosantiago, i founded the answer using the query,
ORDER BY CASE `codigo`
  WHEN '35'   THEN 1
  WHEN '42'   THEN 2
  WHEN '2625' THEN 3
  WHEN '126'  THEN 4
  WHEN '273'  THEN 5
  WHEN '2002' THEN 6
  WHEN '189'  THEN 7
  WHEN '1890' THEN 8
  WHEN '2345' THEN 9
  WHEN '2849' THEN 10
  WHEN '210'  THEN 11
  ELSE 12
  END ASC

Answer (score 0):

I followed the recommendation of @adelriosantiago, i founded the answer using order by case.

```
 SELECT codigo,classificacao,descricao,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (1) THEN IFNULL(saldo_anterior,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS saldo_anterior,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (1) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m1,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (2) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m2,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (3) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m3,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (1,2,3) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS t1,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (4) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m4,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (5) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m5,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (6) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m6,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (4,5,6) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS t2,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (7) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m7,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (8) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m8,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (9) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m9,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (7,8,9) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS t3,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (10) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m10,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (11) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m11,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (12) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS m12,
ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (10,11,12) THEN IFNULL(credito-debito,NULL) ELSE  NULL END)) AS t4,
ABS(SUM(IFNULL(debito-credito,NULL))) AS acumulado
FROM tbl_balancete
WHERE cod_empresa = '557' -- COD IGUAL AO COD INFORMADO NO INPUT
AND YEAR(periodo) = 2019 -- ANO IGUAL AO ANO INFORMADO NO INPUT
AND 
(
classificacao IN ('1.1.01.02','1.1.02.01','1.1.07.01','1.1.10.01','1.2.02.01','1.2.03.01')
OR 
codigo IN ('35','126','273','2002','189','1890','2345','2849','2030','1890','189','4427','3031','2695','4428','6185')
)
GROUP BY codigo, classificacao, descricao
ORDER BY CASE `codigo`
 WHEN '35'   THEN 1
 WHEN '42'   THEN 2
 WHEN '2625' THEN 3
 WHEN '126'  THEN 4
 WHEN '273'  THEN 5
 WHEN '2002' THEN 6
 WHEN '189'  THEN 7
 WHEN '1890' THEN 8
 WHEN '2345' THEN 9
 WHEN '2849' THEN 10
 WHEN '210'  THEN 11
 ELSE 12
 END ASC
```